# validate existing user's mobile number in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase project which allows users to login only if they are already exists in identifier in authentication . 
I already added few users using my web app with mobile numbers. 
Now, in android I have used the `signInWithPhoneAuthCredential` method to get the users login. 
But in this method, it allows any users to login even if the user is first time entering the mobile number.
Is there any method to restrict this ?

Sample Code :

```
private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");

                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        // ...
                    } else {
                        // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs:

> `signInWithPhoneNumber`:
>
> Asynchronously signs in using a phone number. This method sends a code via SMS to the given phone number, and returns a firebase.auth.ConfirmationResult. After the user provides the code sent to their phone, call firebase.auth.ConfirmationResult.confirm with the code to sign the user in.

This is the default behavior in all applications that uses phone number as login. There is no method in the firebase docs that can restrict this.

Comment: By using firestore is this possible to restrict?

Comment: both firestore and realtime database use firebase auth, in firebase auth there is no method that restricts it. Ofcourse you can lets say register using email and password and store in firestore and add the user info in firestore, then if user info is not inside firestore u can restrict it

Answer (score 1):

you have to use firebase database also with this code to save user info, that way you can achieve your use case

Comment: So, there is no way to restrict existing mobile number?

Comment: not only using firebase auth, you can restrict it using Auth and Database combined